# Convert cartesian to cylindrical equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Convert $y = x$ from cartesian to cylindrical.

Clearly, by definition, $x = r \cos(\theta)$ and $y = r \sin(\theta)$.

So the equation $y = x \implies y - x = 0 \implies r(\sin(\theta) - \cos(\theta)) = 0$

Is that the final converted form?

Comment: You could solve that equation further...you can say $r=0$ or $\sin(\theta)-\cos(\theta)=0$.  The last equation you are just finding $\theta$ such that $\sin(\theta) = \cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Since the equation $y = x$ represents a line through the origin making an angle of 45 degrees (in 2D) and a plane containing this line (in 3D) with positive x - axis, the cylindrical equation would be $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

Edit: If you can see a '-' after $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$, then please ignore it. It is not meant to be there but somehow I am not able to delete it.